# cannot push entity to db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to push my Notulen entity to my MySql Database but for some reason it does not work.
However i can push the Meeting entity to the database. Meeting has an one-to-many relationship to Notulen.

The error message is

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

The Exceptions:

> UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELE

The stack trace of the exception is:

> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func 2 updateFunction)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.b__35()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func 1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()

the providers:

```
 <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
 <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
```

This is how i am inserting the notulen entity:

```
 public void Add(List<NotulenModel> notulens, int id)
    {
        foreach (NotulenModel notulenmodel in notulens)
        {
            Notulen notulen = new Notulen();

            notulen.meeting_id = id;
            notulen.persoon = notulenmodel.persoon;
            notulen.punt = notulenmodel.punt;
            notulen.uitkomst_punt = notulenmodel.uitkomst_punt;
            dbContext.Notulens.Add(notulen);
        }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

NotulenEntity:

```
public partial class Notulen
{
    public int meeting_id { get; set; }
    public string persoon { get; set; }
    public string punt { get; set; }
    public string uitkomst_punt { get; set; }

    public virtual Meeting Meeting { get; set; }
}
```

MeetingEntity:

```
 public partial class Meeting
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Meeting()
    {
        this.Notulens = new HashSet<Notulen>();
    }

    public int meeting_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime datum { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Notulen> Notulens { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And which exception?

Comment: "for some reason it does not work" - did you try reading the exceptions? They contain messages and a type. Instead of this information (which you regard useless) you tell us the stack trace - which is definitely less useful than the exact exception.

Comment: what is inner exeption message?

Comment: this is the exception: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

Comment: You still don't show the inner exception. Only its stack trace.

Comment: Please do note that what you added **was not** the inner exception but the stack trace. Set a breakpoint and check the property named `InnerException` of the exception that you got.

Comment: UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT
`Notulen`.`meeting_id`, 
`Notulen`.`persoon`, 
`Notulen`.`punt`, 
`Notul' at line 1

Comment: MySQL support isn't built into EF 6, which MySQL provider are you using? Microsoft lists several: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/providers/

Comment: @Axel, you can edit your own question and add the relevant details. Just click the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62300487/edit) right before the comments

Comment: You can't use `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />` to talk to MySQL.

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry for that. got another one.  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c42d"></provider>

Comment: It is just going to pick the first provider.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Removed the first provider and tested it. I get the same error.

Comment: Hmm, probably more configuration problems. This will probably help you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html.

Comment: What is the PK on this Notulen table/entity?

Comment: @StevePy FK meeting_id acts as an unique id for the table

Comment: Then your definitions/mappings will be incorrect. Your classes are defined as a 1-to-many between meeting and notulen where a Notulen has a meeting and a meeting has a collection of Notulen. What you would want is a 1-to-1 relationship where a Meeting only refers to a single Notulen instance /w a HasOne/WithOne relationship. The Notulen entity definition will also need to be configured to recognize meeting_id as it's Key. (As that column name does not match EF's default convention) This means either setting up a Entity configuration, using the `[Key]` attribute, or mapping using `ModelBuilder`